# How to use a pipe in a script optionally

Tags: terminal, bash

How can I achieve the conditional usage of a pipe for a command execution in a script.

It looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
XCPRETTY=" | xcpretty"
if [ $(which xcpretty | wc -l) == 0 ]; then
    XCPRETTY=""
fi
xcodebuild archive ....... $XCPRETTY || exit 1
```

Comment: As an aside, be sure to prefix your `xcodebuild` calls with [`xcrun`](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xcrun/) to ease future changes to Apple's developer tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `cat` as a no-op if `xcpretty` is not installed:

```
XCPRETTY="xcpretty"
which xcpretty || XCPRETTY="cat"
xcodebuild archive ....... | eval $XCPRETTY || exit 1
```

Comment: The assignment could also be written as `XCPRETTY=$(which xcpretty && echo xcpretty || echo cat)` which may be hard to understand later :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the shell builtin `eval` to construct the command but your code becomes unclear. It would be much better to write your code as:

```
if  type xcpretty
then
    xcodebuild.... | xcpretty
else
    xcodebuild....
fi
```

Comment: Well, I am having lots of commands that I would like to insert this pipe

Comment: ... so a redundant if then switch is not preferred